# MQTT Entity in home assistant is hidden by integration

Tags: home-assistant

I'm trying to add new MQTT switch to home assistance.
I'm publishing these topics and payload:

```
client.publish("home/bedroom/switch1/available", "online")
client.publish("home/bedroom/switch1/state", "on")
```

But looks like the entity is hidden and therefore I can't add it to the dashboard:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks!